# Wrapping word with Hyphen not work

Tags: c#, wpf, word-wrap

I have a textblock who contains a message with Hyphen. I want that all word who contains hyphen is interpret like a really word like word with non-breaking space.
I got this for the moment:

```
test test test test Test-
test
```

And i want

```
test test test test 
Test-test
```

I feel that the hyphen is a special character for separation in a word and it why i can't wrapping the word.But Any idea for do this?
I try to use this IsHyphenationEnabled but i really don't know his job...

!!!Attention!!! i don't want to break the word, i want a new line when a word with hyphen can't to insert in a line because it don't have any space for the word

Thanks you guys,
Best regards.

Comment: [IsHyphenationEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.ishyphenationenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) works other way around, it helps you to break the word.

Comment: IsHyphenationEnabled just separate a word who can't to be wrapping like this : segment with is IsHyphenationEnabled become seg-ment. It's not that i want. I don't to break the word, i want just want a newline when word with hyphen can't to be in the same ligne like my exemple

Comment: I understand your concern. IsHyphenationEnabled help you to break a long word but you wanted to keep the broken word together. btw what do you think about removing the hyphens so that it become a single word. I am not sure if that work in all scenarios. lets see how we can solve the issue.

Comment: Yeah if i remove hyphen it's good but i can't remove. The message is a project specification. And we can't work with => remove hyphen before display for a good wrapping and remit hyphens after.

Comment: You may perhaps use a converter just for display purpose, so no need to modify original value.

Comment: I think a converter is before display. So that can't work. The probleme is the display by the textblock. I try to override the wrapping but i found nothing for the moment...

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample which converts the value for display only.

```
<Grid xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF"
      xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="testString">some string with non-breaking space</sys:String>
        <l:HyphenRemover x:Key="HyphenRemover" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Nomal string: " />
            <Run Text="{StaticResource testString}" />
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Hyphen removed: " />
            <Run Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource testString}, Converter={StaticResource HyphenRemover},Mode=OneWay}" />
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

above example is for ilustration purpoes the binding can also be done directly to textblock

eg

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource testString}, Converter={StaticResource HyphenRemover}}" />
```

HyphenRemover converter

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    class HyphenRemover : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string text = value as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            {
                return text.Replace("-", string.Empty);
            }
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

result

[image: result]

you can see that the converter is able to modify the value for display without modifying the source.

Comment: Yesit's a good approch, i will try this. At the moment, i add \n with at the good placement in my text but it's really not the best.

Comment: Humm when you said that :"you can see that the converter is able to modify the value for display without modifying the source." Xhat do you mean? You can see that the converter remove hyphen and it's all. I Think the only solution is to add \n :(

Comment: I mean to say that by using converter we did not modify the source value but the temporary value used for display in the text block only.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by determining where line breaks should be placed manually. In my case, I have a method on the control that contains my TextBlock that I feed the text into, but this could also be used in a dependency property if you want to set the text in XAML.

```
public void ProcessText(TextBlock target, string text)
{
    //get display info about text block
    var maxLength = target.ActualWidth - target.Padding.Left - target.Padding.Right;
    var textBlockTypeFace = new Typeface(target.FontFamily, target.FontStyle, target.FontWeight,
        target.FontStretch);

    var words = text.Split(' ');
    var currentLine = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        var word = words[i];

        //account for spaces between words if it's not the last word
        if (i == words.Length - 1) {
            word += " ";
        }

        var formattedText = new FormattedText(currentLine + word, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight, textBlockTypeFace, target.FontSize, target.Foreground);

        //if the line we're building fits, add the word to the text block and keep building the current line
        //otherwise, add a line break to the text block before adding the word and reset the current line
        if (formattedText.Width < maxLength)
        {
            currentLine += word;
            target.Text += word;
        }
        else
        {
            target.Text += Environment.NewLine + word;
            currentLine = word;
        }
    }
}
```